How to add subtitles using FFmpeg-kit?
I'm running a Flutter app with Ffmpeg-kit package to burn a subtitle on a video. I have a words list with the timings and map that to generate an srt and ass file, but when executing this it didn't work.
Firstly, here is how I generated the Ass file.
Future<String> _createAssFile() async {
    String filePath = await getAssOutputFilePath();

    final file = File(filePath);
    final buffer = StringBuffer();

    // Write ASS headers
    buffer.writeln('[Script Info]');
    buffer.writeln('Title: Generated ASS');
    buffer.writeln('ScriptType: v4.00+');
    buffer.writeln('Collisions: Normal');
    buffer.writeln('PlayDepth: 0');
    buffer.writeln('Timer: 100,0000');
    buffer.writeln('[V4+ Styles]');
    buffer.writeln(
        'Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding');
    buffer.writeln(
        'Style: Default,Arial,40,&H00FFFFFF,&H000000FF,&H00000000,&H80000000,1,1,1,1,100,100,0,0,1,1,1,2,10,10,10,1');
    buffer.writeln('[Events]');
    buffer.writeln(
        'Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text');

    // Write events (subtitles)
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.words.length; i++) {
      final word = widget.words[i];
      final startTime = _formatAssTime(word['startTime'].toDouble());
      final endTime = _formatAssTime(word['endTime'].toDouble());
      final text = word['word'];

      buffer.writeln('Dialogue: 0,$startTime,$endTime,Default,,0,0,0,,$text');
    }

    await file.writeAsString(buffer.toString());
    return filePath;
  }

  String _formatAssTime(double seconds) {
    final int hours = seconds ~/ 3600;
    final int minutes = ((seconds % 3600) ~/ 60);
    final int secs = (seconds % 60).toInt();
    final int millis = ((seconds - secs) * 1000).toInt() % 1000;

    return '${hours.toString().padLeft(1, '0')}:${minutes.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${secs.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}.${(millis ~/ 10).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

Then I used this command which was the official way of adding ass file to a video.
  String newCmd = "-i $videoPath -vf ass=$assFilePath -c:a copy $_outputPath";

Yet when executing this command it did not work. However I changed it to this command
String newCmd = "-i $videoPath -i $assFilePath $_outputPath";

Well, that code works but the styling is not being applied. So I tried yet another command to filter and position the ass file.
String newCmd = "-i $videoPath -i $assFilePath -filter_complex \"[0:v][1:s]ass=\\an5:text='%{event.text}',scale=iw*0.8:ih*0.8,setdar=16/9[outv]\" -map [outv] -c:a copy $_outputPath";

This made it even worse, because the app crashed when I ran this. Also there is a log for this command before crashing
F/libc    (19624): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x19 in tid 21314 (pool-4-thread-7), pid 19624 (ple.caption_app)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/a15nsxx/a15:14/UP1A.231005.007/A155FXXU1AWKA:user/release-keys'
Revision: '5'
ABI: 'arm64'
Processor: '7'
Timestamp: 2024-07-10 19:27:40.812476860+0300
Process uptime: 1746s
Cmdline: com.example.caption_app
pid: 19624, tid: 21314, name: pool-4-thread-7  >>> com.example.caption_app <<<
uid: 10377
tagged_addr_ctrl: 0000000000000001 (PR_TAGGED_ADDR_ENABLE)
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0000000000000019
Cause: null pointer dereference
    x0  0000000000000001  x1  b400006ec98d8660  x2  0000000000000000  x3  0000000000000002
    x4  0000006f62d1ea12  x5  b400006e04f745ea  x6  352f35372f64352f  x7  7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
    x8  632ace36577a905e  x9  632ace36577a905e  x10 0000006e191378c0  x11 0000000000000001
    x12 0000000000000001  x13 0000000000000000  x14 0000000000000004  x15 0000000000000008
    x16 0000006e27ffa358  x17 0000006e27dbfb00  x18 0000006e00d48000  x19 0000006f62d1f0e8
    x20 0000006f62d24000  x21 0000006e27ffc5d0  x22 0000006e27ffc5f0  x23 0000000000000000
    x24 b400006f3f089248  x25 0000006f62d1f220  x26 b400006f3f057b20  x27 0000000000000002
    x28 0000000000000088  x29 0000006f62d1f100
    lr  0000006e27dbfb0c  sp  0000006f62d1f0a0  pc  0000006e27dbfb10  pst 0000000060001000
1 total frames
backtrace:
      #00 pc 0000000000121b10  /data/app/~~oWqjrGA2indQhuEw6u_J2A==/com.example.caption_app-u2Ofk54FVtMc5D-i3SLC6g==/base.apk!libavfilter.so (offset 0x10a46000) (avfilter_inout_free+16)    
Lost connection to device.

I tried the normal command in my local machine on Windows, and this is what I used
ffmpeg -i F:\ffmpeg\video.avi -vf subtitles='F\:\\ffmpeg\\caption.srt':force_style='Fontsize=24' F:\ffmpeg\new.mp4

As you can see above when subtitles are used it had an extra backslashes for each path and a pre backslash after the partition letter. But I don't know if this does apply for android devices. How can I make sense of this?
